# How to write a Conditional Selection SQL QUERY in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.3, sql

```
$collection->getSelect()->where($getMainTableAlias.'.entity_id IN (SELECT catText.entity_id FROM '.$catalogCategoryEntityTextTable.' as catText where catText.attribute_id="'.$attributeId.'" AND  FIND_IN_SET("'.$groupId.'", catText.value) GROUP BY   catText.entity_id)');
```

I have this query. I have to remove the first where clause so as to avoid any filters but the rest will remain same. How can I perform this task?

Comment: All where query or only first where query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with this and add your table name from which you want to get the records.

```
$collection->getSelect()->SELECT * FROM 'YOUR TABLE NAME';
```

hope it works.

Comment: Actually didnt find any such examples so I was confused if it is possible that way?

Comment: It is possible I implement it my self in some places

Comment: if I write only till getselect() what will be the difference in output?

Comment: And its not working I think Its fetching some connection to the main table from the first where clause. but I am confused.

Comment: null, because query starts after getSelect(), you can print the query echo $collection->toString()

Comment: I didn't check your condition, only I corrected the syntax as per your requirement it depends on you that, what you want to get from the table. you can modify your query as per your needs

Comment: According to your original query it perform a filter based on some entity id, which it gets from the nested(inside) query.

Comment: I want a query that will not filter anything but fetch everything.

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TEST implements ObserverInterface
{

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $orderIncId->delete();
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tblname= //Table_Name;
        $tableName = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName($tblname);
        $sql = //Your Custom SQL Query;
        $connection->query($sql);
        $this->registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
}
```

}

**May It would help**

Comment: without registry is it possible to use $sql = //Your Custom SQL Query;
        $connection->query($sql) ?

Comment: No you have to include registry

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understand what you have meant by `remove the first where clause so as to avoid any filters`.

Then you can use the below code:

```
    $collection->getSelect()
            ->where($getMainTableAlias.'.entity_id IN (SELECT catText.entity_id FROM '.$catalogCategoryEntityTextTable.' '
                    . 'as catText where catText.attribute_id="'.$attributeId.'" AND '
                    . ' FIND_IN_SET("'.$groupId.'", catText.value) GROUP BY   catText.entity_id)');
    // fine the Where condition of collection
    $wherePart = $collection->getSelect()>getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);

    // remove all where condition from Collection

    $collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);

    // Remove first condition from $wherePart variable

    if(!empty($wherePart)) {
        // remove first where
        unset($wherePart[0]);
    }
    // Apply Rest of all where condition on collection Again
    if(!empty($wherePart)) {
       $collection->getSelect()>setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE,$wherePart);
   }
```

Using `getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)` you can remove all where condition from the query.

Comment: na only first where query